# PHP Store array values

Tags: php, arrays, function, output

Hi I am using maxmind minfraud. And I got the result like this:

> err=;countryCode=IN;ip_region=25;ip_city=;ip_latitude=10.0223;ip_longitude=30.2433;highRiskCountry=No;queriesRemaining=1075;cityPostalMatch=;shipCityPostalMatch=;ip_domain=;ip_countryName=;ip_continentCode=AS;ip_corporateProxy=No;shipForward=NA;riskScore=0.20;prepaid=;minfraud_version=1.3

Here I want to return as array value.

```
<?php

function fraudQuery($ip, $country_code, $state, $city, $area_code, $mail_domain,$address)
{
 $d = file_get_contents("https://minfraud.maxmind.com/app/ccv2r?license_key=".IP_LOOKUP_KEY."&i=$ip&country=$country_code&city=$city&postal=$area_code&domain=$mail_domain&shipAddr=$address&shipCity=$city&shipRegion=$state&shipPostal=$area_code&shipCountry=$country_code");

 return array('Errors' =>err,  'IpCountryCode' => countryCode, 'IpCountry' => ip_countryName, 'IpRegionCode' => ip_region, 'IpRegion' => ip_regionName, 'IpCity' => ip_city, 'IpHostName' => ip_domain, 'Score' => riskScore);

}
?>
```

How to return as array value like this. Thanks

Comment: You would need to explode the result by `;` and then explode again by `=` which should give the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
parse_str(str_replace(';','&',$yourresultfromURL),$matcharray);
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/147036)</kbd>

---

#### Explanation :

Replacing `;` by `&` inorder to bring that to `parse_str` format and finally those matches are moved to `$matcharray` array.